# web2py SQLFORM accepting too fast

Tags: sql, web2py

I have a web2py SQLFORM that gets generated and returned by an AJAX call and the form is put in a DIV I defined.. I want that SQLFORM to be an update form, not an insert form. The problem is the form immediately runs it's accept function once it is written to that DIV. This doesn't happen if the form is for inserting, only updating. That initial accept fails and hitting the submit button does not allow for a second accept.
I don't know why the accept fails or why it happens immediately.

heres the JavaScript function that makes the AJAX call

```
function displayForm(currID){
    //Remove everything from the DIV we want to use
    $('#window').empty();
    //Call the ajax to bring down the form to update the series
    ajax('{{=URL('newForm')}}/'+currID,
    [], 'window');
}
```

And here is the newForm controller

```
def newSerForm():
record = db.myTable(request.args[0])
form = SQLFORM(db.myTable, record, fields=['series_name','image_thumbnail'])
if form.accepts(request.vars,session):
    print 'Series update successful!'
else:
    print 'Series update Failed...'
return form
```

displayForm is fired by clicking a button and once you do the form accepts and fails and the submit button doesn't work again. Is there a way to make an SQLFORM do this? The weird thing is if I change this to make inserts into myTable, it works fine. It behaves exactly as it should. But doing it this way doesn't work.

Ok now this is where it gets weird.
I tried to achieve the same functionality here with a totally different approach, an iFrame. I made new functions in my controllers that create the form based on request.args[0]. looks like this

```
def editEntry():
print request.args[0]
record = db.myTable(request.args[0])
form = SQLFORM(db.CC_user_submission, record, fields=['series_name', 'image_thumbnail']).process()
return dict(form=form)
```

And then a corresponding HTML page that just displays form. What could be simpler right? I go to that page based on a link that gives the correct argument. Take me to a page with a form for updating. Updating works perfect. Great, now lets put it in an iFrame instead of linking to it. I put it in an iFrame on the original page. Open up the iFrame. Doesn't work. I have no idea what is going is there any part of an explanation to this?

Answer (score 0):

By using the iFrame method I actually got this one to work. Since it required an iFrame to be appended with jQuery which needs quotes and the iFrame URL which also needs quotes, the notation got pretty confusing but it's doable. Looked like this:

```
var myURL = "{{=URL('editEntry')}}/"+idArg.toString();
$('#window').append("<iframe src = " + myURL + "  width='450' height='400'> </iframe>");
```

It's not pretty but it works.